# Multiple SSH ports for Synology Diskstation DSM 5.1

Tags: ssh, nas, port, synology

I have a Synology Diskstation that I recently upgraded to DSM 5.1 (5004). I previously had my system configured to allow connections on both port 22 and port 10000. After the upgrade, it appears that my sshd_config file was reconfigured, so altered it again to specify:

```
Port 22
Port 10000
```

My firewall is configured correctly and indeed I can connect to both ports. However, with both root and non-root accounts, I can correctly login to port 22 using publickey authentication but not port 10000. Using either publickey or password authentication on port 10000 returns the message:

```
Permission denied, please try again.
```

I've looked around at the Synology forum and other places and there is acknowledgement that the system changed in 5.1. There is now UI to specify an SSH port, but not to specify 2 ports. However, none of the posts seem to indicate how to successfully use two ports. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at /etc/synoinfo.conf for DSM 5.1. Unsure if it allows you to have multiple ports though.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you'd want two ports but an easier (imo) way to achieve this (assuming you don't need port 10000 from inside the LAN) is just to forward port 10000 on your router to port 22 on the Syn in addition to forwarding 22 to 22.  Thus you get both ports to access port 22 from the WAN and need no config changes on the Syn server (changes that will always get borked with every DSM update..)